# I would like this jquery ui code explained please

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I was reading this code (http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager), 
but couldn't understand one specific line

```
var $gallery = $( "#gallery" ),
    $trash = $( "#trash" ); 

$( "li", $gallery ).draggable({ //This is the line a I can't understand well
        cancel: "a.ui-icon", 
        revert: "invalid", 
        containment: "document",
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move"
});
```

why is the $gallery there? it's not making the $gallery draggable, only `<li>` is draggable.

It seems that only `<li>` inside `#gallery` can be dragged, but that's easily done with `$("#gallery li")` or `$("#gallery > li")`

So what's different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd argument to the `$()` function is the `context`.  It's equivalent to:

```
$gallery.find('li');
```

Yes, in this case, you can also do: `$("#gallery li")`, but the `context` option is good, when you are just passed a DOM element or jQuery object, and don't know its selector.

Comment: Thanks man, I got it now, I didn't know about this second argument, could you give me an example of a code where it is really usefull?

Comment: @Dave: If you're making a jQuery plugin.  All you have is the jQuery object, not its selector.  So, if you want to find children, `$('li', $gallery)`, is shorter than `$gallery.find('li');`.

Answer (score 0):

According to jQuery documentation: "The `$("> elem", context)` selector will be deprecated in a future release. Its usage is thus discouraged in lieu of using alternative selectors."

Probably they will adapt the code in Photo Manager when it gets deprecated. I don't see any differences in usage, it just looks "less jQuery".

Comment: Where do you see `$("> elem", context)`?

Comment: It's `$("elem", context)`, but seeing that `$("> elem", context)` will be deprecated, I wouldn't use this construction.

Comment: The part that is deprecated is using `>` at the beginning of the selector to find immediate children of the context element(s) - providing a context in a general sense is fine.